# Get local state folder content in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, uwp

I'm working on my final assignment in school and I set my goal to make UWP app that manipulate with HTML files.
I managed to make files and folders in LocalState folder, but getting list of files there has stopped any progress on project for few days now, I know how to handle files with IO but as I realized that won't work in my case.

So maybe if any of you have an idea how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

I know this is probably basics for lots of you and I'm really sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Code below is my last attempt:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Seznam_map().Wait(1);
            }
private async Task Seznam_map()
            {
                StorageFolder Projects = await Skupno.domacamapa.GetFolderAsync("Projects");
                var files = await Projects.GetFilesAsync();
            }

Skupno.domacamapa = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is asynchronous and you just wait 1 millisecond for the result. Try making it async and await for the result:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Seznam_map();
}
```

I'm also not sure what you do with the `files` later once you get them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I most certainly ow you a beer, as I said I'm not familiar with asynchronous tasks. I would like to get list of all files (folders & files) so I can offer them to "user" in list view. I guess if I know location, I can read them with IO library, right?

Comment: @LaurentResman In UWP I would do things via *StorageFolders* and *StorageFiles*. If you want to make a list of files, then use *StorageFolder's* *GetFolders/GetFiles* or *GetItems* methods. If you want to open a file, then open it and get a stream - [MSDN has quite good docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) about it. You may also want [to read more at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/).

Comment: Thanks for such quick reply, so not `Skupno.domacamapa.GetItemsAsync()`? How would you do it? I know how to add stuff on list, and set path to them, just need list of names. Thanks for all your time, you already helped me a lot, with other async voids.

Comment: @LaurentResman That's what I would do - use `Skupno.domacamapa.GetItemsAsync()` for getting files and folders, then use *ObservableCollection* to list them. Everything depends on your needs. Give it a try and debug.

Comment: I read MSDN about reading and writing to a file and I accomplished that. But so far didn't accomplish to get list of files, thanks for all your time and helpful answers again.

Comment: accomplished much more than I hoped for with your solution, I just have one more question, how can I do the same for subfolder? `IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> datoteke_vmapi = await Skupno.domacamapa.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (IStorageItem item in datoteke_vmapi)
            {

                LW_seznam_strani.Items.Add(item.Name);
            }`

Comment: @LaurentResman The subfolder (*IStorageItem*) is also a *StorageFolder*, you can cast `(StorageFolder)item` or use `item as StorageFolder`, then list items the same as before.

Comment: Thanks again, you are awesome! @Romasz , everything works now